# Did the Harry Potter movies influence JKR's later HP books?

Tags: harry-potter, adaptation-comparison, jk-rowling, inspiration

The *Harry Potter* books were published in 1997, 1998, 1999, 2000, 2003, 2005 and 2007.

The *Harry Potter* movies were released 2001, 2002, 2004, 2005, 2007, 2009, 2010, 2011.

As can be seen, the last 3 books were written after 2 movies came out; the last 2, after Movie #3, and *Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows* after 5 movies.

Is there any evidence from the publisher or JK Rowling that the later books were in any way influenced by the earlier movies? (sets, scripts, visuals, feel, characters, whatever)?

Comment: you may also find [this question](http://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/2117/how-is-the-relationship-between-the-reader-and-the-story-affected-by-movies-that) I asked on the now extinct Literature SE that was migrated to Movies and TV.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I'm not sure about sets and scripts, but one of the actors did have *some* influence: Evanna Lynch's portrayal of Luna Lovegood.

According to Charlie Rose interview with JKR in 2012 (quote on Wikipedia article for the actress), she said:

> "I saw her. [She] got in my head. I even heard her voice when I was writing Luna.

Not quite earth-shattering as far as influence, but still...

Comment: I've seen claims that JKR made similar comments regarding Rickman's portrayal of Snape, though I've been unable to find a reference on this.

Comment: @AntonMårtensson: I seem to remember that an illustration of Snape at the beginning of a chapter looked mighty similar to Rickman as well, though I don't recall any specifics.

Comment: @AntonMårtensson, reid - Rowling [explicitly requested Rickman for Snape](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/8269/was-the-casting-of-alan-rickman-as-snape-based-on-the-full-knowledge-of-the-futu)

Answer (score 25):

Slughorn's calling Ron "Rupert" was likely a nod to Rupert Grint, the actor who plays Ron in the movies.

Comment: Or just a gaff that was left in.

Comment: See also https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/158812/4918

Answer (score 10):

There is one pretty clear example in *Harry Potter and the Half Blood Prince*:

> "Draco had a look on his face similar to the time Hermione had punched him" ("The Half-Blood Prince")

But in the books, Hermione actually *slapped* Draco.

> Harry and Ron both made furious moves toward Malfoy, but Hermione got there first -- SMACK! She had slapped Malfoy across the face with all the strength she could muster. Malfoy staggered. Harry, Ron, Crabbe, and Goyle stood flabbergasted as Hermione raised her hand again. 'Hermione!' said Ron weakly, and he tried to grab her hand as she swung it back.
>
> 'Get off, Ron!' Hermione pulled out her wand. ("The Quidditch Final")

Rowling accidentally recounted what occurred in the *film* version of *Prisoner of Azkaban*, which was released in 2004, around when she would have been writing the book (released in July 2005).

[image]

Answer (score 8):

### According to set director Stephenie McMillan, the description of Grimmauld Place in book seven was based on the way it appeared in the fifth movie.

> J. K. Rowling visited the studio when the set for Grimmauld Place was being constructed for the first time. The author had described many aspects of the gloomy house without going into great detail, so Stephenie wondered how she would react to the specific designs. "I had a chance to explain my ideas about all the paintwork being black and having grey silk on the walls," she says. "**And then, in the next book in which Grimmauld Place appears, Jo described the walls as covered in grey silk. So the actual set design got into the book.**"
> <sub>*Harry Potter Film Wizardry* - Page 119</sub>

Stephenie is referring to the description of Sirius Black's room in the seventh book. (Rowling's set visit would have happened while she was working on this book.)

> The teenaged Sirius had plastered the walls with so many posters and pictures that **little of the walls’ silvery-grey silk was visible.** Harry could only assume that Sirius’s parents had been unable to remove the Permanent Sticking Charm that kept them on the wall, because he was sure they would not have appreciated their eldest son’s taste in decoration.
> <sub>*Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows* - Chapter Ten - "Kreacher's Tale"</sub>