# How did JK Rowling imagine the voices of her characters?

Tags: harry-potter, jk-rowling

From various illustrations by Rowling herself, we have at least some idea of how she imagined most of her major characters to *look*. For instance, here's a piece of concept art she drew in relation to the first book:

[image: picture]

But what do we know, if anything, about how she imagined them to *sound*?

**What canon info is there on the voices of the major characters in the *Harry Potter* series?**

Comment: I suggest you ask JK Rowling. Perhaps she imagined they all had lisp. Maybe they were all Swiss, Actually, if I recall correctly, they all had a Russian accent.

Comment: What does the writing say? The right-most one looks like it says "Gary" - who is Gary?

Comment: @RedCaio Don't worry man, Gary's cool.

Comment: @RedCaio, does. Gary was Dean Thomas' beta name :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In [this interview](http://www.accio-quote.org/articles/1999/1099-connectiontransc2.htm) with JK Rowling, she describes how she imagines the voices of some of her characters (Hagrid, McGonagall, Dumbledore, and Harry):

> Lydon: Now I want to hear J.K. Rowling herself do ...
>
> JKR: Do Dumble-, er - not Dumbledore - Hagrid!
>
> Lydon: Either one ...
>
> JKR: Well, Hagrid's sort of West-country - yokel - which is where I grew up - the part of Britain where I grew up, I didn't grow up in Scotland, I grew up on the border with Wales. So Hagrid's kind of ... 'Yes Harry Potter, sir' - like that - very slurred words - it's the accent English people always put on to sound stupid ... [laughs] Hagrid *isn't* stupid, but he's got that kind of very country - you know, way of speaking ...
>
> Lydon: And how about Minerva McGonagall?
>
> JKR: Very clipped, and very, very - quite upper-class and very brisk - like a governess [Lydon laughs] I - I - I can't do it, but I kind of see Dumbledore more as a John Gielgud type, you know, quite elderly and - and quite stately.
>
> Lydon: And Harry himself?
>
> JKR: I suppose he sounds like me. I always do my voice for Harry, when I'm reading to my daughter.

The audio of this section of the interview, including a minute or two of JKR reading aloud from her own book, is available [here](http://web.archive.org/web/20100615000000*/http://www.accio-quote.org/audio/connection-1999/15-Voices.mp3) (Internet Archive; sadly the original link has gone dead).

Comment: I'm almost certain she said something separate re: Luna but don't remember if it was the voice. There's a quote elsewhere on the site about that

Comment: @rand Your link is now working. I verified a copy available through the Internet Archive.

Comment: @DVK I'm hoping for one of your awesome character-limit-approaching answers to this one...

Comment: @DVK-in-exile After casting, Evanna Lynch's voice [was in JKR's head while writing](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/28027/30255).